# How to source another file in xonsh?

Tags: xonsh

In posix shells it is `. filepath` and in bash you can do `source filepath`.

What is the equivalent in xonsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can source a xonsh file by path with the [`source` builtin command](https://xon.sh/aliases.html#source), e.g.:

```
@ source ~/.config/xonsh/rc.xsh
```

will re-source a xonshrc in that location.

You can also source `.xsh` files with `import` ([docs](https://xon.sh/tutorial.html#importing-xonsh-xsh)). This requires the xonsh file to be in a directory that is in `sys.path`, or in the current directory. The above example with `import` instead looks like this:

```
@ cd ~/.config/xonsh
@ from rc import *
```

Finally, if you want to source files written for *other* shells, there is also [`source-foreign`](https://xon.sh/aliases.html#source-foreign), and its shortcut aliases like [`source-bash`](https://xon.sh/aliases.html#source-bash), which will pull in any changes to environment variables and aliases.